# Exercises for May's "A concise course in Algebraic Topology"

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is there some place to find chapter-appropriate questions for [Peter May's book](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/maybook.pdf) "A concise course in Algebraic Topology"? In particular, if there's a list that shows which questions of, say, Hatcher one ought to attempt for every chapter of May's book, that would be amazing! Otherwise, it's unclear to me how much of the material I've really understood.

Comment: The book itself contains problems. The methods and techniques are quite different between the two books, they are not all that compatible in my opinion. I would read Hatcher to do Hatcher problems. Otherwise, you can just look at the names of the sections (eg. "fundamental group") to see roughly corresponding topics.